# Access windows directory from a web application PHP

Tags: php, windows, web, web-applications, shell-exec

I'm New to PHP programming. I'm searching for a solution. After googling a lot, finally i'm here.

My Assignment is like : 'My web application have to detect the device connected to the PC with a name say "My_DEVICE" and if it is found programtically, i should generated a file and keep it in the device. If device is removed and again connected, i should check for a directory as per some....specifications and upload the images into the server'.

I have done it in my local XAMPP server, it's working fine. Whereas when i upload it into the server, i facing the problem. Please help me.

My Code as follows:

```
for($i = 'C'; $i < 'Z'; $i++)
    {
        // Try to grab the volume name
        if (preg_match('#Volume in drive [a-zA-Z]* is (.*)\n#i', shell_exec('dir '.$i.':'), $m)) 
        {
            //$volname = ' ('.$m[1].')';

            if ($m[1]=='MY_DEVICE')
            {
                $path = $i.":/";
                if ($dh = opendir($path)) 
                {
                    if(file_exists("myfile.txt"))
                    {
                       //my logic here
                       echo "file already exists";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $file = fopen("myfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
                        $id=$myid."\r\n";                   
                        fwrite($file, $id);                         
                        fwrite($file, $name);
                        fclose($file);
                    }
                }
                $device = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            //echo "No SMARTSCOPE device";
            $device++;
        }
    }
}

    if($device==0)
    {       
         echo '<h1 align="center" style="padding-top:40px">You Plugged-in Device !!</h1><br />';
    }
    else
    {
         echo '<h1 align="center" style="padding-top:40px">No Device detected !</h1><br />';
    }
```

When i debugged, i came to know that shell_exec unable to find the path. How to access windows directory from a web application. Is any api's are avaiable? or any libraries are available?

Please help and guide me in the situation. Thanks in Advance !!

Comment: Permission of the folder maybe?

Comment: Are you trying to access the device/folder on your local computer from the server?

Comment: your webserver account is HIGHLY unlikely to have permission to write in the root directory of C:, or any other drive... if you want to test if a drive exists, then try `is_dir('C:/.')` instead.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn Yes i'm trying to access the device on my local system from the server.

Comment: @MarcB Tried it ! No Luck.

Comment: @DineshM That would be a MAJOR security violation. Imagine any website you visit has access to devices on your computer. They could load/execute all sorts of malicious code on your computer by visiting the site. Or download your passwords on your computer or run any software. Unless you somehow hook the device through your browser as a plugin (some devices allow this like card readers) then it won't be possible to access anything.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn How can i try this from client side javascript? Please guide me.